# How to add iText into my netBeans project?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, netbeans-8, jdk1.7

Im using **Netbeans** 8.0.2 and I am trying to give my output as a PDF file. On a quick google search, I learnt **iText** can help me do it. But how can i import iText package into my project?

How should i import the package that i have downloaded (latest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project uses Maven then you simply add iText to your `pom.xml`.

`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.8</version>
</dependency>`

See http://developers.itextpdf.com/itext-java

Comment: When i added these dependencies in pom file and added to my project as library, it shows error in these lines    `import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;`

Comment: ??? It shouldn't do that... I am not familiar with NetBeans but it sounds like there is something wrong with where it looks for iText in the build path.

Answer (score 0):

Find itextpdf.jar into http://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases/latest .zip file and add to project. Also have other jars for import to java project inside the .zip file.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Add your dependency to your pom.xml file and click on project "Resolve Project Problems" -> Resolve...