# Creating PDF using JAVA (Netbeans) with images and multi pages

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans, itext

I am developing a Java program with the following requirements:

- The application will take 5 input fields and 3 images (browse and "attach" to the Java application).
- Once the "form" is completed it will be submitted using a button called "submit".
- Once submitted the JAVA application will create a PDF file with the 5 inputed text and the 3 attached images.
- I should be able to control which goes to which page number.

How do I implement such a solution with iText?

Comment: I believe you're mistaken about iText - that library allows to create awesome PDFs with pretty simply code. You might want to check it out in more detail.

Comment: i need a library that allows me to create a PDF file from inputs and images i attach/give to it. by the way checking iText site it seems its no longer free?

Comment: @JamesAnd *I'm aware of iText but it doesnt let you control the PDF at all* - this is totally incorrect. Instead of claiming such nonsense, you could have asked about how to implement a solution using iText.

Comment: @JamesAnd _by the way checking iText site it seems its no longer free?_  On http://itextpdf.com/Pricing, at the bottom of the page, you find information about the AGPL version of iText, which has 100% exactly the same functionality as the commercial version. More details on http://itextpdf.com/agpl

Comment: Will this be a desktop application or a web application or an Android app or... ? It's not clear what you are asking. However, putting 5 strings and 3 images in a PDF is trivial. See the developer site for examples: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples Depending on what you mean by the word "form", you might not even need XML at all. Based on your comment below @alex-m's answer, I don't think you do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add iText into my netBeans project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565883/how-to-add-itext-into-my-netbeans-project)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - The application will take 5 input fields and 3 images (browse and "attach" to the Java application).
> - Once the "form" is completed it will be submitted using a button called "submit".

These first two requirements are unclear; are they to be implemented in a Java GUI (AWT? Swing? FX?), in some independent web UI (Plain HTML? Vaadin?), or in some derived UI (Portlet? ...)?

But as the question title "*Creating PDF using JAVA (Netbeans) with images and multi pages*" focuses on the PDF creation, let's look at the third and fourth requirements.

> - Once submitted the JAVA application will create a PDF file with the 5 inputed text and the 3 attached images.
> - I should be able to control which goes to which page number.

Let's assume you already have those inputs in the variables

```
String text1, text2, text3, text4, text5;
byte[] image1, image2, image3;
```

### The framework

With iText you now create the document like this:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

...

// where you want to create the PDF;
// use a FileOutputStream for creating the PDF in the file system
// use a ByteArrayOutputStream for creating the PDF in a byte[] in memory
OutputStream output = ...; 
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
document.open();

// Add content for the first page(s)
...
// Start e new page
document.newPage();
// Add content for the next page(s)
...
// Start a new page
document.newPage();
// etc etc

document.close();
```

### Adding text

You can add text in one of the `Add content for the ... page(s)` sections using

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;

...

document.add(new Paragraph(text1));
```

### Adding an image

You can add an image in one of the `Add content for the ... page(s)` sections using

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;

...

document.add(Image.getInstance(image1));
```

### Adding at a given position

Adding text or images as described above leaves the layout details to iText, and iText fills the page from top to bottom except some margins.

If you want to control the positioning of the content yourself (which also means you have to take care that the content parts do not overlap or are drawn outside the page area), you can do so like this:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;

...

PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(text2);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase, 200, 572, 0);

Image img = Image.getInstance(image2);
img.setAbsolutePosition(200, 200);
canvas.addImage(img);
```

And there are many more options how to manipulate your content, e.g. choosing a font, choosing text sizes, scaling images, rotating content, ..., simply have a look at the [iText samples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition) from the book *iText in Action - Second Edition*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **XSL-FO**. A basic example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37663/PDF-Generation-using-XSLFO-and-FOP). After this, you can search and add other options for your PDF.

Comment: thanks! but how can i start by creating an XSL file before PDF?

Comment: You create an xsl file based on some model object, then the xsl file will create an xml file that will be transformed/translated into a pdf file. About the model, it can be a class with 5 attributes (your 5 input fields) and a List of images. More examples about process [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/17/xsl-fo/index.html?page=2) and about model to xml [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/12/jaxb-tutorial-xml-binding.html) and [here](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~zp/aulas/1314/pde/geral/bibliografia/XML%20By%20Example.pdf).

Comment: I don't think the OP is using XML at all, but the question is unclear.